# MySQL blob to file with bash. Why did this corrupt my data?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, blob

I'm in a situation where I can't use MySQL Dump. It's a long story, but in short the server is crashing due to i/o problems related to VMWare snapshots.

Therefore I have to resort to writing a script to try and extract my binary data record by record.

Here's an example of what I tried:
`mysql -u root -pPASSWORD --max-allowed-packet=1G -N -e 'select version_binary FROM version_binary WHERE version_id = 100' my_database > my_file`

This produces a file that is roughly (not exactly) the correct size, but the file is corrupt.
**Why?**

If I convert to hex in the query:
`mysql -u root -pPASSWORD --max-allowed-packet=1G -N -e 'select HEX(version_binary) FROM version_binary WHERE version_id = 100' my_database > my_file.hex`

and then use:
`xxd -r -p my_file.hex output.bin`

it works.

Unfortunately using hex consumes way more space and takes significantly longer (I'm dealing with 500GB of data and around 1/2 million records) so I would really like to get the straight binary method to work.

**EDIT:**
After a little further investigation it seems that the corrupt binary has extra \n sprinkled throughout. [The version on the left is not corrupt (extracted as hex and converted to binary) the version on the right is corrupt (extracted directly).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqfcK.png)

Comment: I would shut down mysqld, and then `rsync` the whole MySQL datadir to another server instance that is not crashing.

Comment: No way of knowing *why* the output of your query is corrupt. It could be the data in already corrupt in the database. It could be mishandled by character set encoding as you query it. It could be corrupted as it writes the output to my_file, especially if you have I/O errors happening.

Comment: This is probably a character set issue. If you're interpreting binary data as UTF-8 you can be in for some ugly surprises. Also worth noting this is why people start to freak out when anyone suggests putting large amounts of binary data into a database.

Comment: @BillKarwin can't use rsync. As soon as the i/o gets too high, the filesystem becomes read only. The only way I can extract the data is record by record and slowly. Also, the data is not corrupt in the tables (the hex method works just fine).